# Annotate seaborn clustermap with Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, heatmap, seaborn

I am using seaborn (v.0.7.0) to plot a heat-map. Here is my code:

> Updated code after fixing the problem

```
### Get Data
sns.set(style="white")
adata       = pd.read_csv("Test.txt", sep="\t",index_col=0)
adata_log   = np.log2(adata)
e           = adata.iloc[0:7,0:3]
e_log       = adata_log.iloc[0:7,0:3]

#### Set up the matplotlib figure
f, ax       = plt.subplots(figsize=(11, 9))

#### Set color
hmcol       = ["#ffffff","#ffffff","#fbe576","#c06e36","#9a2651"]
cmap        = sns.blend_palette(hmcol,as_cmap=True)

#### Plot clustermap
sns.set(font_scale=0.8) ## 0.8 for normal use
aplot = sns.clustermap(e_log,cmap=cmap,method='average', metric='euclidean',standard_scale=None,row_cluster=False,col_cluster=False,row_linkage=None,col_linkage=None,linewidths=.05,square=True,annot=e,annot_kws={"size": 15},fmt='.2f')

aplot.cax.set_visible(False) #remove color bar
plt.setp(aplot.ax_heatmap.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=90) ## Y-Axis label rotations
plt.setp(aplot.ax_heatmap.yaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=0) ## X-Axis label rotations

##Save Figure
aplot.savefig(“Test-Fig1.0.pdf",orientation='potrait',dpi=600)
```

Is there any way I can use values in the dataframe ‘e’ as annotations? I tried

> annot=e

in clustermap but its giving me an error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Also, it there anyway I plot the figure in landscape mode? Here is the data and figure from above code:

```
print(e)

        X       Y      Z
A  100.72   90.20  13.58
B  160.98  162.24  12.85
C    6.76    8.03   0.66
D  241.49  277.89  29.43
E  156.78  145.54  30.72
F    6.09    5.96   0.93
G    4.57    1.16   0.74
```

[image: Test Plot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading 'seaborn' to v0.7.1 solved the annotation problem. I have updated my answer with fix.

For plotting in landscape, I guess easiest way would be to change my data from tall to long order i.e. change the input test file file by copying data and pasting as transposed.

Bade

Comment: you could simply transpose your data (df.T)